# Readonly file and can't change permissions

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, readonly

There is a file with `read only` permissions, but even `root` can't `chmod` it.

Permissions of the file: `-rw-r--r--`

After trying to `chmod 777`:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘motd’: Operation not permitted
```

I'm doing it from the `root` account. How is it possible to lock a file like this?

Comment: `lsattr /etc/motd` and check if the immutable bit is set.  You will see an `i` in the output if it is.

Comment: What filesystem is this file on?

Comment: Yeah it was lsattr I used chattr and I can change it now, thanks ;)

Answer (score -3):

Verify the ownership of the file with

```
ls -l
```

Change ownership of the file with

```
chown root motd
```

Comment: root is the owner ;(
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      989 Sep 19 17:20 motd

Comment: @Furjoza But the dot at the end of the permission string indicates it has extended permissions.  Edit in your question the output of `ls -Z /etc/motd` and `lsattr /etc/motd` and `lsattr -d /etc`

Comment: Root doesn't need to own the file to modify either the file or the properties.